# Mutation-summary in Chrome not performing callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

I'm using the Mutation-summary Javascript library to monitor the DOM on Tumblr and create an alert when a new page is loaded. On Tumblr, for those who don't know, there is a sort of 'infinite scrolling' feature where the current page will autoload the next page if the user scrolls down far enough. The next page is appended to the current page using jQuery.

My script:

```
var observer = new MutationSummary({
    callback: theNextPageLoaded,
    queries: [{
        element: "#container"
    }]
});

function theNextPageLoaded(summaries) {
    alert("The next page loaded!");
}
```

For some reason, even though the element with the id "container" is visibly altered, the callback function never gets called, and so the alert message never appears. The new page is not appended to #container, but rather a child or grandchild of #container. I'm not sure exactly what, but that shouldn't matter, as if the child is altered, then the parent is as well in this case.

Here is a simple JSFiddle illustrating my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/jcZ84/

Comment: Can you write a self-contained example to demonstrate the problem? A visual change in an element doesn't necessarily trigger the Mutation Observer. Keep in mind that Mutation observers are triggered on attribute modification, and generally not for properties modifcation.

Comment: Do you know of a way that would allow me to trigger something like this when the body or content of a div is changed, rather than just attributes of it?

Comment: I've added a JSFiddle to show what I mean. I'm referring to the actual displayed content of the div when I say change. Like, content is added or removed from the div.

Comment: That fiddle is expected to do nothing. Do you want to get notified for non-node modifications? Use http://jsfiddle.net/jcZ84/2 The element selector does not match the ancestor of a mutation, but the target - http://jsfiddle.net/jcZ84/3/ / http://jsfiddle.net/jcZ84/1/. If you want to restrict the match to a certain ancestor, set the `rootNode` property - see https://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/wiki/APIReference#MutationSummary_Constructo

Comment: I feel stupid now, thank you Rob! It didn't occur to me that I should be setting the element selector to match the classes that are being appended to the page. I changed my element selector to ".post_container" because post_container divs are the things being added to the page. Thanks again!